# is it a structure or an internal table?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF PPP
        ------
       END OF PPP,

   xxx TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF PPP
```

My question is will `xxx` be an internal table or a structure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it will be an internal table. its lines will be of the type PPP.

Answer (score 3):

```
DATA: xxx TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF PPP, "produces table with lines of type ppp
      yyy type PPP.                    "produces flat structure of type ppp.
```

yyy is a structure of type PPP and can be appended to xxx since they are of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> TYPES: BEGIN OF PPP
>     ------
>    END OF PPP,
>
> xxx TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF PPP
> ```

xxx won't be either a structure or an internal table, but a table type.

If you declare:

```
DATA: lt_xxx TYPE xxx.
```

Then you would have a standard internal table with its structure based on PPP structure definition (since xxx is a table tabe based on PPP).

Answer (score 1):

Here XXX will be the internal table - that hold the structure of PPP

Answer (score 0):

Paulo is right;

> xxx won't be either a structure or an internal table, but a table
>   type.

Or you can create Structure or Internal Table with statement below:

```
DATA: ls_xxx  TYPE ppp. " <<-- Structure
DATA: lt_xxx  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ppp. " <<-- Internal Table
DATA: lt_xxx2 TYPE xxx. " <<-- Internal Table
```